# Distriubtion of $Y = \frac{X_1}{X_1^2+...+X_n^2}$, where $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, 1)$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, chi-squared

Obviously, the bottom is a chi-square and the numerator is normal, but I'm not sure how to calculate the distribution of $Y = \frac{X_1}{X_1^2+...+X_n^2}$. With each $\mu_i$ distinct and not necessarily equal.

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. There will be no nice expression for this distribution.

Comment: @zhoraster I've tried computational methods to get the shape but it's not particularly helpful

Comment: @zhoraster it actually looks very normal when I do the simulations if that helps